# Books on Hyperfine Splitting (Theoretical Physics)

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, orbitals

Do you have any good recommendations on books (theoretical physics) about hyperfine splitting?

Comment: Can you add more details to the post, such as your current level of education (grad, undergrad; relevant courses taken such as QM, LinAlg, etc) and what books you may have looked at already. The more information you provide, the better recommendations we could provide.